# ElasticSeach query not return results

Tags: elasticsearch

I got 2 querys, the different between them is just 1 filter term.

The first query:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "*"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": {
                    "filters": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "type": "log"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "context.blueprint_id": "adv1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "context.deployment_id": "deploy1"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

return this result:

```
{
            "_source": {
               "level": "info",
               "timestamp": "2014-03-24 10:12:41.925680",
               "message_code": null,
               "context": {
                  "blueprint_id": "Adv1",
                  "execution_id": "27efcba7-3a60-4270-bbe2-9f17d602dcef",
                  "deployment_id": "deploy1"
               },
               "type": "log",
               "@version": "1",
               "@timestamp": "2014-03-24T10:12:41.927Z"
            }
         }
```

The second query is:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "*"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": {
                    "filters": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "type": "log"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "context.blueprint_id": "adv1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "context.deployment_id": "deploy1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "context.execution_id": "27efcba7-3a60-4270-bbe2-9f17d602dcef"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

return empty results.

the different between them is in the second query, i just add this term:

```
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "context.execution_id": "27efcba7-3a60-4270-bbe2-9f17d602dcef"
                        }
                    }
```

and in the result we can see that there is result match to that query, but it still not work.

what i'm doing wrong here?

thanks.

Comment: What does your mapping look like ? is the `context.execution_id` analyzed ?

Comment: i'm new in elasticSearch, what do you mean analyzed?

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html#default-analyzers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ElasticSearch will treat string fields as text and will analyze them (i.e. tokenize, stem etc. before indexing). This means you might not be able to find them when searching for their exact content.

You should make sure the mapping for the `execution_id` field is not analyzed. Start with `GET /_mappings` and work from there. :)